# Creating time marks for speech audio with existing text

Tags: speech-recognition

My case: I have audio of speech and already prepared text of same speech.

And I need add time marks for text, so I can move between audio parts with help of text hints.

As I can see Google's Speech-to-Text allow achieve that. My question is any alternatives? Maybe self-hosted open-source solutions, or paid cloud services?

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/ might give some good starting points.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Transcribe is an alternative, it provides timestamp for each word transcribed

- https://aws.amazon.com/transcribe/features/?nc=sn&loc=2
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/how-input.html#how-output